# Loop that asks for a guess a certain number of time?

Tags: java

I am making a code that takes either 5, 10, or 20 guesses from a user. 
Depending on how many guesses the user chooses, my program should make a loop and ask that many times to see if the user can guess the random number. This loop will iterate as long as the user hasn't guessed the number and hasn't reached the limit of the guesses. Here is an example of what the output should look like.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange.  This is not a homework writing service.  You must at least attempt to solve the problem, and show your attempt, and ask where you went wrong.  See [mcve] for examples on how to ask better questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= numberOfGuesses; i++){
   System.out.print("Enter guess #"+i+": ");
   guess = scan.nextInt();
   if (guess > randomNumber && guess <= 100)
      System.out.println("Your guess, "+guess+", is less than the magic number.");
   else if (guess < randomNumber && guess > 0)
      System.out.println("Your guess, "+guess+" is greater than the magic number.");
   else if (guess == randomNumber){
      System.out.println("Congratulations, "+name+"! You guessed the magic number in "+i+" guesses");
      break;
   }
   else
      i--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go through the following code which I provided inline comments about the logic. If you have any point which difficult to understand put a comment on the answer.

```
package src.main;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NewClass {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int guess;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print(" Please enter your name: ");
    String name = scan.next();

    System.out.print(" Would you like to try to guess a number? (Yes or No):");
    String answer = scan.next();

    if (answer.length() == 3)
        System.out.print("How many guesses would you like? (5, 10, 20)");
    int numberOfGuesses = scan.nextInt();

    Random random = new Random();

    int randomNumber = random.nextInt(100 - 0 + 1) + 0;
    int actualGuessCount = 0;

    // Check whether the number of Guess attempts not exceeded
    while (actualGuessCount <= numberOfGuesses) {
        // Increase the number of Guess attempts by one
        actualGuessCount++;

        System.out.print("Enter guess #" + actualGuessCount + ":");
        guess = scan.nextInt();

        // Check the Guess value and random value same
        if (guess == randomNumber) {
            System.out.println("Congratulations, " + name + "! You guessed the magic number in " + actualGuessCount
                    + " guesses.");
            System.exit(0);
        } else if (guess < randomNumber) {// Check guess value less than the
                                            // random value
            System.out.println("Your guess, " + guess + ", is less than the magic number");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Your guess, " + guess + ", is greater than the magic number");
        }

        // If the number of attempts equals to requested attempts program
        // will exit
        if (actualGuessCount == numberOfGuesses) {
            System.out.println("You consume all the guesses.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here you go**

```
    import java.util.*;

    public class peasy {
    public static void main(String[] args)
        {

            String name,guess;
            int choice,i,Userguess,magic;
            Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter your name:");
            name = a.next();
            System.out.print("Would you like to try a guess number? (Yes or No):");
            guess = a.next();
            if (guess.equals("No")){
                System.exit(0); /* we do not need to write for Yes as the program will as default */
            }


            System.out.print("How many guess would you like? (5 ,10 ,15): ");
            choice= a.nextInt(); /*CHoice stores the total guess user wishes to make*/

            Random number = new Random(); 
            magic =1+ number.nextInt(100); /* Creates a random number from the range 1 to 100 */

            for(i=0;i<choice;i++)
            {
                System.out.printf("Enter you guess #%d :",(i+1));
                Userguess=a.nextInt(); /* stores the guess of user*/
                if(Userguess == magic)
                {
                    System.out.printf("Congrulations %s ! You guessed the magic number in %d guesses \n",name,Userguess ); /* displays the messsgae if the guess is correct*/
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                if(Userguess < magic)
                {

                    System.out.printf("Your guess %d is less than the magic number",Userguess ); /*displays a message by checking if the number entered is less than the magic number*/
                }
                if(Userguess > magic)
                {

                    System.out.printf("Your guess %d is more than the magic number",Userguess ); /*displays a message by checking if the number entered is more than the magic number*/
                } /*closing parenthisis*/
            }

    }
}
```